# 16-bit bitwise and in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, logical-operators

If I needed to perform a bitwise AND operation of two 16bit inputs and obtain a 16bit output in VHDL, would I be able to just AND the two inputs and store the result as the output vector?  Or would I need to loop through each bit of the inputs, AND them, then store the result in the output vector?  Would this work similarly for operations like or and xor?

Comment: It's very easy to try these things. Just write a small bit of code like PlayDough and I have done and see if it compiles and does what you expect. EDA Playground is great for doing just that.

Answer (score 7):

The "and" operator is overloaded in the `std_logic_1164` package for `std_logic`, `std_ulogic`, `std_logic_vector`, and `std_ulogic_vector` (the types typically used).  It is also defined for `bit` and `bit_vector` (as well as `signed` and `unsigned`).

So it is as straightforward as just applying the "and"operator.  For example:

```
architecture rtl of test is
  signal a : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal b : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal y : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
begin
  y <= a and b; -- Or 'y <= a xor b;' or 'y <= a or b;', etc
end architecture rtl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `and`.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity and_gate is
port(
  a: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  b: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  q: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));
end and_gate;

architecture rtl of and_gate is
begin
  q <= a and b;
end rtl;
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Xuw