# Is "xor" bitwise or logical in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

For instance, in Verilog by contrast, there is "logical and" and "logical or":

```
   //Verilog
   x = a && b;  //logical "and"
   y = a || b;  //logical "or"
   y = !a;      //logical "not"
```

and then there's "bitwise and", "bitwise or", and "bitwise xor":

```
   //Verilog
   x = a & b;  //bitwise 'and'
   y = a | b;  //bitwise 'or'
   z = a ^ b;  //bitwise 'xor'
   q = ~a;     //bitwise 'not' or negate
```

My question is, for VHDL, is "xor" logical or bitwise when applied to a std_logic_vector, unsigned, signed, or bit_vector, types:

```
-- VHDL
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity top is
   port(y :out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture rtl of top is
    signal a: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := X"11";
    signal b: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := X"F0";
begin
    y = a xor b;  --bitwise or logical?
    y = a and b;  --bitwise or logical?
    y = a or  b;  --bitwise or logical?
    y = not a;    --bitwise or logical?
end architecture;
```

Comment: Similar if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949206/16-bit-bitwise-and-in-vhdl/35949418

Comment: I'm going to guess VHDL is always "bitwise" and never "logical" unless you convert the type to a scalar type: std_logic, bit, or boolean.   Mostly, because VHDL is based on ADA language, a strongly typed language, and verilog is based on the c-language a weakly typed language that needs to make a distinction between logical and bitwise operator because you can place boolean logical results in any data type with casting.   What about integer type in VHDL?  "bitwise" or "logical"?

Comment: Logical operators are predicated on Boolean or other 'bit' representing types. VHDL  or Ada Integers are mathematically defined as value ranges while in Verilog or C are based on underlying integer types comprised of bits subject to bitwise operators while logical operators evaluated non-zero integer values.VHDL rray types with elements representing 'bits' also can have logical operators which are 'bitwise'. VHDL -2008 has the "??" condition operator (which may be implicit) for evaluating enumerated 'bit' types to Boolean values.  Array values have no Boolean equivalent.

Comment: For array values whose elements represent 'bits' you can use VHDL -2008 unary reduction "or" along with the condition operator to evaluate the zero or non-zero Boolean value. The condition operator can require parentheses, see the BNF in IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.Expressions, 9.1 General, 9.2 Operators (precedence).

Comment: @pico: Verilog isn't *remotely* based on, or similar to, C. Some operators use the same symbols, but expression evaluation, and everything else, is completely different.

Answer (score 4):

"logical" operators in Verilog (and C) are just an abbreviation resulting from the (mathematically incorrect) definition that anything nonzero is assumed "true" while a zero value is assumed "false". Such

```
(a != 0) & (b != 0)
```

is abbreviated as

```
a && b
```

and

```
(a != 0) | (b != 0)
```

is abbreviated as

```
a || b
```

in VHDL, you have to write the complete expression.

```
(a /= "0000") or (b /= "0000")
```

(assuming you are comparing to a 4 bit `bit_vector`)

VHDL 2008 makes this a little less verbose. It has binary reduction operators that operate on vectors by applying the operator between all the elements of the vector, i.e.

```
(or "0001")
```

reduces to '1' and

```
(or "0000")
```

reduces to '0'. So in VHDL 2008, you can write

```
(or a) or (or b)
(or a) and (or b)
```

for the 'logic' operators instead.

Comment: That’s an Interesting way of looking at it.

Comment: At the risk of appearing smart-arse, I'd rather say that's the *correct* way of looking at it. ;)

Comment: might be worth adding that not all synthesis tools that claim to support VHDL 2008 indeed support reduction operators. Quartus II, for example, doesn't  (so at least for Quartus users - unless they implement binary reduction as functions themselves  - the last part of the answer is rather theoretical)

Comment: Verilog doesn't assume non-zero is true - it has to be non-zero and known, so 2'b1x evaluate 'false'. I'm not sure how any mathematical definition of false/true could be relevant, though - it's common in computing to classify values as zero or non-zero.